# How to scrape multiple pages using the apple i tunes api

Tags: python, itunes-api

I'm trying to scrape the Itunes API to get information for all of the podcasts available in the Apple iTunes store. Currently, I'm only able to pull 200 at a time. When I try to grab the next 200 podcasts in the list, I'm getting the same 200 as before.

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&limit=2
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&limit=2&offset=1

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import json

url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&limit=2' 
res = requests.get(url,headers={'User-agent': 'project'})
res.status_code
current_url = None
posts = []
the_offset = 0
for _ in range(2):
    if current_url == None:
        current_url = url

    else:
        current_url = url +'&offset={}'.format(the_offset)
        res = requests.get(current_url)
    if res.status_code != 200:
        print('Error',res.status_code)
        break
    the_offset += 1
    current_dict = res.json()
    current_posts = {k:v for (k,v) in current_dict.items()}
    posts.extend(current_posts['results'])
    print(current_url)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the offset parameter:

```
results = 100
limit = 10

pages = int(results / limit)

for i in pages:
    offset = i+1
    request(offset)
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems like the offset isn't being recognized.

Comment: i got different data using offset=1 and offset=2